# Various Errors with creating calendar entries

Tags: clio-api

I'm struggling to be able to create calendar entries on particular calendars. I get a variety of errors, most often 404, but also 500 errors. I'm following the Clio API v.4 documentation, which I notice doesn't provide a way to specify *which* calendar to create an entry on, though it does allow you to specify the calendar owner, which might be the solution except users might have multiple calendars.

I'm sending POSTS to `https://app.clio.com/api/v4/calendar_entries.json`

Here's the JSON I'm sending in the POST:

```
{"data":{
"summary":"string",
"matter":{"id":integer},
"start_at":"ISO 8601 Date",
"end_at":"ISO 8601 Date",
"desription":"string"
}}
```

This returns a (500) "InternalServiceError."

If I modify it to specify a calendar owner I get a (404) "NotFoundError", Like so:

```
{"data":{
"summary":"string",
"matter":{"id":integer},
"start_at":"ISO 8601 Date",
"end_at":"ISO 8601 Date",
"calendar_owner":{"id":integer},
"desription":"string"
}}
```

I've played around with alternative formulations with no luck. In `"calendar_owner":{"id":x}` I've exchanged the owner's user id with the `calendar_id`, to no avail. I've added a key/value pair for `calendar_id:integer`, with no luck. I've also modified the URI for the post to `https://app.clio.com/api/v4/calendar_entries/`x`.json` where x is the `calendar_id`.

I don't think I'm missing anything that's in the documentation, but I'm definitely missing something. The token I'm using has the appropriate scope and is for a user with either owner or editor permission on the calendar.

Any fixes here?

Comment: Hi Jacob.  Do you still have the issue, or is the endpoint now working as expected?

Comment: Yeah O was able to get this to work, thanks!